# How to tabularize with delimiter of groups of spaces in Vim

Tags: vim

I have some lines like this

```
abc  defg  hijklmnopq
abc    defghi  jklmn opq
abc  defgh  ijklmno pq
```

I want them to be tabularized into at most three columns with at least 2 spaces in between columns, i.e.

```
abc  defg    hijklmnopq
abc  defghi  jklmn opq
abc  defgh   ijklmno pq
```

What [`Tabularize`](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) command should I use in Vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your input and output samples, the following command should do it.

```
:Tab /\s\+\zs\s/l1c0
```

You can abbreviate `:Tabularize` to `:Tab` to save a few keystrokes. The regular expression relies on a property of your data, namely that there is more than one space character separating the columns; otherwise it would be impossible to know which text belongs to which column.

We choose the final space as the delimiter character and then align the text left with a padding of 1. The `\s` serves as the second padding space.

In the future, and as always, please consider the `:help`. `:help tabular` has extensive and very readable documentation that describes in detail all of the above.